# Selenium: what difference between JUnit and testNG to parallel the tests?

Tags: selenium, junit, testng

I am discovering selenium and more precisely selenium grid which allows the creation of nodes and the execution of parallel tests on several browsers.

I was wondering what the difference is between these 2 frameworks: is there one that performs better than the other?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per *Cédric Beust's* [TestNG Documentation](https://testng.org/doc/):

> TestNG is a testing framework inspired from JUnit and NUnit but
> introducing some new functionalities that make it more powerful and
> easier to use, such as:
>
> - Annotations.
> - Run your tests in arbitrarily big thread pools with various policies available (all methods in their own thread, one thread per test class,
>   etc).
> - Test that your code is multithread safe.
> - Flexible test configuration.
> - Support for data-driven testing (with @DataProvider).
> - Support for parameters.
> - Powerful execution model (no more TestSuite).
> - Supported by a variety of tools and plug-ins (Eclipse, IDEA, Maven, etc...).
> - Embeds BeanShell for further flexibility.
> - Default JDK functions for runtime and logging (no dependencies).
> - Dependent methods for application server testing.
>
> TestNG is designed to cover all categories of tests:  unit,
> functional, end-to-end, integration.