# Selenium Python webdriver condition

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, safaridriver

My script can give me 3 separate webdrivers based on what I want i.e., my script can either install the *chromedriver* or *safaridriver*, or *firefoxdriver*. As an example:

- *`chromedriver`*:

  ```
  <selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="8032fa9146e8fc2a764aa278a1521014")>
  ```
- *`safaridriver`*:

  ```
  <selenium.webdriver.safari.webdriver.WebDriver (session="7703B595-D074-40C4-82D5-D4A265C2AAB2")>
  ```
- *`firefoxdriver`*:

  ```
  <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver (session="d2549d48-bec3-4ccc-b95f-7339bbe4ca60")>
  ```

What is the best way to have the script run differently based on browser?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) *Java* clients and a framework like [*TestNG*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70523488/7429447) you can use the *`@Parameters`* tag to choose the browser of your choice through [testng.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49152209/7429447) as follows:

```
private WebDriver driver;

@Parameters ({"browser"})

@BeforeTest

public void preCondition(String browser)
{
    try
    {
        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox"))
        {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }

        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome"))
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }

        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("IE"))
        {

            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        }                   
    }

    catch (WebDriverException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Browser not found" +e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This approach will be the best approach to download, create and use any type of [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48080871/7429447)

Comment: Downloading and installing the webdriver  at runtime, is not a problem @undetected Selenium. My original question was how do I make my script run differently based on browser?